# How do I create a model that functions as a button in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

I'm new to Unity. I created a button with some functionality behind it. I also have a 3D-model. I would like to assign the funtionality to my model instead of to my button. This way you can click the model and it will activate my script.

What's the best way to do this?

I'm using Unity 2019.2.12f1 and Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just by adding a script to model would not call `OnMouseDown()` function. You need to do the following things first:

(a) Add a box collider to your model
(b) Scale the box collider so that it covers the whole model (including edges), you will see green lines drawn as box
(c) Add the below function to your script and attach this script to your model:

```
public void OnMouseDown()
  {
     Debug.Log("Model Clicked");
  }
```

(d) Now when you click on the model, the function will be called

Answer (score 0):

Use the `OnMouseDown()` function. This function is activated whenever it registers a click event on the 3D-model. Here is further documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html.

Comment: I added the script to my model but it still doesn't activate the OnMouseDown() function when the model is clicked. Note that my model is just a standard model in a Canvas. Could it be that I'm missing something?

Comment: @TimMG Does your model have a collider attached?

Comment: @Saif explains the process you have to go through well, try following his steps.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `OnMouseDown` but rather implement your own button class using the [`IPointerXYHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/Manual/SupportedEvents.html) interfaces somewhat like

```
public class CustomButtom : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    public enum ButtonState
    {
        Normal,
        Hover,
        Pressed,
        Disabled
    }

    public UnityEvent onClick;

    private bool _isDisabled;
    public bool IsDisabled
    {
        get => _isDisabed;
        set
        {
            SetState(value ?ButtonState.Disabled : ButtonState.Normal);
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter (PointerInputEvent eventData)
    {
        if(_isDisabled) return;

        SetState(ButtonState.Hover);
    }

    public void OnPointerExit (PointerInputEvent eventData)
    {
        if(_isDisabled) return;

        SetState(ButtonState.Normal);
    }

    public void OnPointerDown (PointerInputEvent eventData)
    {
        if(_isDisabled) return;

        SetState(ButtonState.Pressed);

        onClick.Invoke();
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerInputEvent eventData)
    {
         If(_isDisabled) return;
        SetState(ButtonState.Normal);
    }

    private void SetState(ButtonState state)
    {
        // TODO: handle states to change styles etc as feedback

        _isDisabled = state == ButtonState.Disabled;
    }
}
```

This has to be placed on the 3D/2D object. If it is a UI element you are fine. If it is a 3D object it needs a `Collider`, an `EventSystem` in the scene and the camera a `PhysicsRaycaster` component.